# jQuery dialog button styling

Tags: jquery, css, dialog

I have three projects that I am working on.  All of them use the dialog approach to adding or viewing data elements.  I have styled the dialog buttons like this:

```
 function addNewDialogButtons(buttons, id) {
var buttonPane = $(id).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonset');
$(buttonPane).empty();
$.each(buttons, function (index, props) {
    var newButton = $('<button></button>', {
        id: 'btn' + id + props.id,
        text: props.text
    });
    newButton.button().unbind().on("click", props.click);
    newButton.css('font-size', 'x-small').css('background-color', 'whitesmoke').css('color', 'blue').css('border', '1px solid blue').css('border-radius', '10px');
    $(buttonPane).append(newButton);
});
}
```

Each page does this:

```
 buttons = [{ text: "Cancel", click: function () { CloseDialog("#divDetails") } }, { text: "Save Changes", click: function () { UpdateStatus() } }];
                addNewDialogButtons(buttons, "#divDetails");
```

This works great on my development PC and for two of the projects on production server.  One of them though does not show the styling.  I cannot figure out what the difference is.  Any help would be appreciated.  Just ask what you need to see.

Comment: are you sure that all required js and css files deployed to production server?

Comment: @teran - yes, of course, because the function addnewdialogbuttons is in a separate JS file, which I can see on the server and made sure the CSS styling was there.  It is there but it doesn't work for only one of my projects, the other two are fine.  I cannot figure what the difference is.

Comment: Weird situation! I also think that the way you set your `newButton.css` is not the right way. What will happen if you change it to: `newButton.css({
    font-size: "x-small", 
    background-color: "whitesmoke", 
    color: "blue", 
   border: "1px solid blue",
   border-radius: "10px"
});`

Comment: @Rotan075 - that approach does not even work in the JS file.  Filled with red errors.

Comment: @Rotan075 if I use single quotes around everything, it takes and works fine on my development machine but, it still does not work on the server.  Also, I made a change to alternating row colors in Site.css and it does not show on the server either.  Have any idea?

Comment: @Dean.DePue if you open your developer tool within chrome/ie or firebug in firefox and you navigate to the tab: sources. Do you see the desired changes been made to your Site.css? Because if you do not see it. Then your did sync the server I guess.